# Why can't we say the word "hell"?

Tags: minhag, words, gehinnom

It seems to me that in many Orthodox communities it is considered improper to say the word "hell". Why is this so? Why is it any worse than saying "Gehenim" or "Purgatory"?

Comment: Is this true of parallel words in other cultures? You might just be witnessing an American phenomenon http://english.stackexchange.com/q/133328/19365 Unless the phenomenon you have seen is unique in some way to Jewish communities (in which case you should edit how in), I can't see how this is on topic. In many Orthodox communities people put Ketchup on fries, but that doesn't make the practice on topic here.

Comment: I had a Rebbi which would say that if you do something bad you will go to hell,not gehenom, he explained that gehenim sounds too nice,hell has more of an effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably mainly because it can be a mild curse word when used in different contexts and therefore, fairly or unfairly, it is associated with crassness in people's minds. (In addition, those Orthodox Jews may simply be accustomed to saying most religious terms in Hebrew.)